# What's the meaning of method com.sun.beans.TypeResolver#fixGenericArray?

Tags: java

i do not understand the meaning of this method, what role does it play?

```java
private static Type fixGenericArray(Type var0) {
    if (var0 instanceof GenericArrayType) {
        Type var1 = ((GenericArrayType)var0).getGenericComponentType();
        var1 = fixGenericArray(var1);
        if (var1 instanceof Class) {
            return Array.newInstance((Class)var1, 0).getClass();
        }
    }

    return var0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved!
The method is used to fix the bug:
 https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5041784

Comment: Great, but what issue? Why do you care?